# ReCaptcha v2.0 customization

Tags: recaptcha

has anyone managed to customize the new `reCaptcha` widget. I need to pass width to it but it is fixed to `300px`? Documentation says nothing on that matter.

Comment: Skins/Themes are not available atm :( I need them too, but probably we have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize "g-recaptcha"-class with css:

```
.g-recaptcha{
   transform:scale(0.8);
   -webkit-transform:scale(0.8);
   transform-origin:0 0;
   -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
}
```